# Travis CI Ruby Version conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, version, travis-ci

I'm currently trying to use TravisCI properly for my rails app but I'm a bit stuck with the problem I'm facing.

In my .travis.yml

I've got this :

```
language: ruby
before_install:
  - gem install bundler
rvm:
  - 2.0.0
env:
  - DB=sqlite
  - DB=mysql
  - DB=postgresql
script:
  - rake db:migrate
  - rake db:test:prepare
```

And in my Gemfile I precise Ruby version : `ruby "2.0.0"`

With this .travis.yml the tests fails saying to me :

> $ gem --version
>
> 2.0.3
>
> $ bundle install --deployment
>
> Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0

But when I modify my `.travis.yml` like this :

```
language: ruby
before_install:
  - gem install bundler
rvm:
  - 1.9.3
  - 2.0.0
env:
  - DB=sqlite
  - DB=mysql
  - DB=postgresql
script:
  - rake db:migrate
  - rake db:test:prepare
```

Travis CI runs the test twice (once for 1.9.3 version and once for 2.0.0 version)
and fails with 1.9.3 version and succeed with 2.0.0 version.

What am I doing wrong in order to just pass the test with 2.0.0 ruby version ?

Cordially rob

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the repository / build you're seeing this on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what was wrong, TravisCI was looking for a .travis.yml in each branch but I only had one in my master branch (I thought TravisCI was only checking master branch).
I added a .travis.yml and all was ok.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Glad you got it working! Since this is the correct answer, any chance you could mark it as "accepted" (click the checkmark next to your answer)?

Comment: I can only "accept" it in 8 hours because I can't simply marked it as "accepted" until I wait 24 hours. Don't worry I'll accept it :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I keep forgetting that they added that limitation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the same error message even though my `.travis.yml` was included. The solution that worked for me was to include the generated `Gemfile.lock` in the repo as well.